# Showing certain collection is orthogonal?

Tags: orthogonality

Show that $\{\phi_n: n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ where $\phi_n:[-\pi,\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\phi_n(x)=e^{inx}$, $x\in [-\pi, \pi]$ is orthogonal.

Here is my attempt; For $k\neq r$ take $\phi_k,\phi_r \in \{\phi_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$ Then

$$\langle \phi_k,\phi_r \rangle=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{ikx}\cdot e^{irx}dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{(k+r)ix}dx=\frac{1}{k+r}\biggl(e^{(k+r)ix}\biggl|_{x=-\pi}^{\pi}\biggl)
$$
Using Euler identity we can easily conclude that
$$\langle \phi_k,\phi_r \rangle=\frac{1}{k+r}\biggl(e^{(k+r)ix}\biggl|_{x=-\pi}^{\pi}\biggl)=0$$

Now my problem is what if $k+r=0$; for if $k+r=0$

$$\langle \phi_k,\phi_r \rangle=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{(k+r)ix}dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx=2\pi.$$

What is wrong with me?

Comment: What definition of the inner product are you using? In the usual $L_2$ case, one of the two terms should be complex conjugated.

Comment: @marana As far as I remember, both the inner product you gave must have the second factor conjugate in the integral,  and it also should be $$\phi_n(x):=\frac1{2\pi}e^{inx}$$

Comment: It should be $e^{-irx}$ instead of $e^{irx}$. and also the $\phi_n(x)$ should be as mentioned by Timbuc in the above comment.

Comment: @Sten: You are right. It is $\langle \phi_k,\phi_r \rangle=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{ikx}\cdot e^{-irx}dx$.